# How can I customize the list item and still have the ribbon

Tags: custom-list, ribbon, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am working on a Sharepoint hosted app and the whole application is created with the concept of SPA. I am using jquery, bootstrap, knockout, etc. to display the list item data.

Is there any way to have the option to display the ribbon for the list and the item?